# distributed cache infinispan and varibale properties in infinispan.xml

Tags: caching, jboss, infinispan, jcache

so I m using infinispan 11.0 in embedded mode and I have two questions :

---

**First question :**

---

I am building an app for a client and I am going to have multiple caches ( local and distributed ).
the thing is when I have **one node alive** is there a possibility to force the distributed caches to work as a local cache ( i mean stop sending messages to sync with the non-existing nodes something like initial_cluster_size but when the node are below the required number the cache will act as a local cache) to ***increase performance.***

---

**Second question**

---

is there a possibility to pass variables in infinispan.xml because the node names are located in another file so is the possibility to reference the value in infinispan ( using spring for example )?

> ps: for this question, I have to deal with infinispan.xml file I know that the request can be treated programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question**

What do you mean by `stop sending messages to sync with the non-existing nodes`? Infinispan does not send messages to "nobody" and, if you have a single node, the distributed cache does not send any messages to the network. See [code here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/infinispan/interceptors/distribution/BaseDistributionInterceptor.java#L252).

**Second question**

Yes, if you load your properties in a Properties object, you can do something like this:

```java
Properties props = ... //my properties
ParserRegistry reg = new ParserRegistry(Thread.current.getContextClassLoader(), false, props);
ConfigurationBuilderHolder holder = reg.parse(/*infinispan.xml path or File*/); //check other parse methods
DefaultCacheManager manager = new DefaultCacheManager(holder, true);
```

Reference the key in your infinispan.xml using `${key}`.

Comment: passing properties file to the constructor can do the same job ? i mean parse infinispan.xml  with the configs passed as parameter...`JCacheManager(URI uri, ClassLoader classLoader, CachingProvider provider, Properties properties) `

Comment: no, Embedded Infinispan does not consume those properties. For remote (Hot Rod client), it overwrites the keys in `hotrod-client.properties`